# How to open a link in the default browser on Firefox OS?

Tags: firefox-os

I have a Firefox OS app where I want a link to open outside of the application (the link is to a different site, and opening it in-application would make the application unusable without a force-quite). How do I do that?

---

[Related bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934295)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to change all the links in the application, you can use WebActivities, e.g. like this:

```
/*
 * Open all external links in the browser
 */
$('a[href^=http]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var activity = new MozActivity({
    name: "view",
    data: {
              type: "url",
               url: $(this).attr("href")
          }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `target="_blank"` on the `<a>` tag:

```
<a href='http://different.site/' target='_blank'>Different site</a>
```

Actually, if you send an app with external links without it to the Marketplace, it should be rejected. so watch out :)

Comment: What if I don't want to open new windows when it's not a Firefox OS app? :\

Comment: Make that up to the build :) When building for app, use `target='_blank'`. When building for the Web, don't use it.

Comment: But I don't have a separate build, it's just a website which is also usable as a Firefox OS app :\

Comment: In that case, you'll have to rely on JavaScript. I'd say it's not the best approach, but it's doable.